# How can I use the same crossvalidation sets in R caret and rsamples

Tags: r, r-caret, tidymodels

I am trying to learn the `tidymodels` ecosystem by converting `caret::train()` code into `tidymodels` workflows.  I am getting differences that I think are a biproduct of the resampling algorithms in `caret` vs. `rsample`.  A colleague wrote a gist showing the differences in datasets with the same seed: https://gist.github.com/bradleyboehmke/7794b79a07afb443da11d930ff84bed7

You can see small differences here in simple models (that I think I coded to be the same):

```
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)
data(ames)

set.seed(123)
(cv_model1 <- train(
  form = Sale_Price ~ Gr_Liv_Area, 
  data = ames,
  method = "lm",
  trControl = trainControl(method="cv", number = 10)
))
```

vs.

```
set.seed(123)
folds <- vfold_cv(ames, v = 10)

the_lm_model <- 
  linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm")

the_rec <- 
  recipe(Sale_Price ~ Gr_Liv_Area, data = ames)

the_workflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(the_rec) %>% 
  add_model(the_lm_model) 


the_results <- 
  fit_resamples(the_workflow, folds)

collect_metrics(the_results)
```

Is there a straight forward way to use `caret` resamples (from `caret::createFolds()`) in a `tidymodel` workflow (that would normally be created with `rsample::vfold_cv()`? I am hoping if I can figure out this detail I can replicate complex old code with the new ecosystem (for teaching).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**. Thanks to Julia Silge comment.

The functions
[rsample2caret() and caret2rsample()](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/rsample2caret.html)

can be used to convert resampling objects between formats.

The answer below can be useful to convert from arbitrary formats to rsample.

**Old Answer**

Here is an approach to convert the output of [`caret::createFolds`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/sail/versions/0.1.0/topics/createfolds) to `rsample`

```
library(caret)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidymodels)

data(ames)

#create train folds
set.seed(123)
folds_train <- caret::createFolds(ames$Sale_Price, returnTrain = TRUE, k = 10)

#get test indexes
folds_test <- lapply(folds_train, function(x) setdiff(seq_along(ames$Sale_Price), x))
```

combine the train and test indexes to create a list of analysis and assessment lists as described in [`manual_rset`](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/manual_rset.html)

```
rsplit <- map2(folds_train,
               folds_test,
               function(x,y) list(analysis = x, assessment = y))

splits <- lapply(rsplit, make_splits, data = ames)
splits <- manual_rset(splits, names(splits))
> splits
# Manual resampling 
# A tibble: 10 x 2
   splits             id    
   <named list>       <chr> 
 1 <split [2637/293]> Fold01
 2 <split [2638/292]> Fold02
 3 <split [2637/293]> Fold03
 4 <split [2637/293]> Fold04
 5 <split [2638/292]> Fold05
 6 <split [2637/293]> Fold06
 7 <split [2637/293]> Fold07
 8 <split [2636/294]> Fold08
 9 <split [2636/294]> Fold09
10 <split [2637/293]> Fold10
```

check to see if same result:

```
set.seed(123)
cv_model1 <- train(
  form = Sale_Price ~ Gr_Liv_Area, 
  data = ames,
  method = "lm",
  trControl = trainControl(index= folds_train))
> cv_model1
Linear Regression 

2930 samples
   1 predictor

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (10 reps) 
Summary of sample sizes: 2637, 2638, 2637, 2637, 2638, 2637, ... 
Resampling results:

  RMSE      Rsquared   MAE     
  56364.67  0.5066935  38575.21

Tuning parameter 'intercept' was held constant at a value of TRUE

the_lm_model <- 
  linear_reg() %>% 
  set_engine("lm")

the_rec <- 
  recipe(Sale_Price ~ Gr_Liv_Area, data = ames)

the_workflow <- 
  workflow() %>% 
  add_recipe(the_rec) %>% 
  add_model(the_lm_model) 

set.seed(123)
the_results <- 
  fit_resamples(the_workflow, splits)

collect_metrics(the_results)
> collect_metrics(the_results)
# A tibble: 2 x 6
  .metric .estimator      mean     n   std_err .config             
  <chr>   <chr>          <dbl> <int>     <dbl> <chr>               
1 rmse    standard   56365.       10 1782.     Preprocessor1_Model1
2 rsq     standard       0.507    10    0.0220 Preprocessor1_Model1

all.equal(
cv_model1$results$RMSE,
collect_metrics(the_results)$mean[1])
TRUE
```

perhaps there is a more straightforward way but I don't use tidymodels to know for sure.

If you did not create folds prior to calling `caret::train`:

```
set.seed(123)
cv_model1 <- train(
  form = Sale_Price ~ Gr_Liv_Area, 
  data = ames,
  method = "lm",
  trControl = trainControl(number = 10, method = "cv"))
```

you can use

```
cv_model1$control$index

cv_model1$control$indexOut
```

to create a `rsample` object

```
rsplit <- map2(cv_model1$control$index,
               cv_model1$control$indexOut,
               function(x,y) list(analysis = x, assessment = y))
```

and proceed as described above.

```
splits <- lapply(rsplit, make_splits, data = ames)
splits <- manual_rset(splits, names(splits))
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to write such a wonderfully helpful response!  This will save me a huge amount of time and energy.

Comment: You might also look at the [`rsample2caret()` and `caret2rsample()` functions](https://rsample.tidymodels.org/reference/rsample2caret.html).